# Issue with restore purchase for auto-renewable subscription

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I followed this [**tutorial**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1458378-in-app-purchase-tutorial-auto-renewable-subscriptions) to add auto-renewable subscription for my app. My app has been released on the app store but I have a very strange problem, which is if a user taps restore purchase button it will unlock the feature without purchasing!. I have worked with IAPs and never this happened before! Here is my code, In `IAPManager.swift`I added two lines of codes, which fires a method when purchase/restore complete.

```
 private func productPurchaseCompleted(identifier: ProductID?) {

    guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

    purchasedProductIDs.insert(identifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
    productPurchaseCompletionHandler?(true, identifier)
    clearHandler()

    //Added by me
    appDefaults.isDirectory(purchased: true)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("completePurchase"), object: nil)

  }
```

In my purchase view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //Register notifications
           NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(completePurchase), name: NSNotification.Name("completePurchase"), object: nil)

    }
```

purchase and restore buttons:

```
//MARK: - Purchase IAP and its methods


  @IBAction func purchaseDirectory(_ sender: Any) {

        purchaseItemIndex(index: 0)
        loading.alpha = 1

    }


    @IBAction func restorePurchase(_ sender: Any) {
        IAPProducts.store.restorePurchases()
        loading.alpha = 1
    }


    private func purchaseItemIndex(index: Int) {
        IAPProducts.store.buyProduct(products[index]) { [weak self] success, productId in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            guard success else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to purchase product",
                                                        message: "Check logs for details",
                                                        preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally completePurchase function:

```
 @objc func completePurchase() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You!", message: "You can now access to directory", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action0 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { (click) in
            self.removeAllViewControllers()
            self.presentViewControlleryStoryboard(id: "HOME")
        })

        alert.addAction(action0)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        loading.alpha = 0
    }
```

Does anybody know why this happens? Is there any difference between for example non-consumable IAP and auto-renewable subscription?

**I have to confirm that restore purchase works as expected in sandbox environment**

Comment: I used SwiftyStoreKit and fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `IAPProducts` is, but since you tagged storekit, you should implement it the way Apple calls for.

[Here is a tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases) from Apple detailing how to do this:

Specifically, this is what you will want to do.

```
/// Called when tapping the "Restore" button in the UI.
@IBAction func restore(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
// Calls StoreObserver to restore all restorable purchases.
StoreObserver.shared.restore()
}
```

Specifically, you will want to utilize [restoreCompletedTransactions()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions) which will allow you to restore auto-renewable subscriptions. Then if that is true you will want to set your `appDefaults.isDirectory(purchased: true)` as true.

Finally, if you want more information to check out, [this is the best guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267) from Apple about resources with IAP (in app-purchases)